# Does the minimal surface system in the plane have the weak unique continuation property?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, cv.complex-variables, elliptic-pde, minimal-surfaces

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbf{R}^2$ be a domain in the plane and suppose that $u : \Omega \to \mathbf{R}^k$ is a smooth function for which the graph of $u$ is a smooth minimal surface in $\Omega \times \mathbf{R}^k$. Suppose that there is some open set $U \subset \Omega$ for which $u \big \rvert_U \equiv 0$. Is it true that $u \equiv 0$ on $\Omega$?

I suspect that if this is true it may have some extremely simple complex analysis proof. And it may follow from newer, more fancy unique continutation theorems.

Comment: Define isothermal coordinates on your surface, and consider the mapping from the coordinates to $\Omega \times \mathbf{R}^k$. In this coordinate system the minimal surface equation reduces to harmonicity of the component functions (under the induced metric). But since you are in 2D, harmonicity is conformally invariant. So your unique continuation follows from the unique continuation property of the flat Laplacian.

Comment: The result holds in arbitrary domain and target dimensions $n,\,m$, with "weak" replaced by "strong". Indeed, the system can be written $g^{ij}(Du)u^{\alpha}_{ij} = 0$ for $\alpha = 1,\,...,\,m$, where $g = I + Du^TDu$. Each component of the map thus solves a locally uniformly elliptic equation with smooth coefficients, for which strong unique continuation holds. (Lipschitz coefficients in fact suffice for the unique continuation result.)

Comment: Alternatively, any $C^1$ weak solution to the minimal surface system (again, arbitrary dimension and target dimension) is real analytic (a classical result of Morrey)

Comment: Thank you very much to both of you.